# How to use "would"?

Tags: would

"In the span of the next two years, Bezos redefined Amazon. During this period, he **would start** to think differently about conventional advertising."

What is the difference if I change "would start" to started?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.  The writer of a past narrative gets to pick the vantage point from which he tells the history.  If you places yourself with Bezos, you may use "would," the past form of "will" to indicate that at some point Bezos was looking forward to a time of different advertising.  If you place yourself in the present, looking back at Bezos' actions, you say "started" to indicate that from the point of view of right now, Bezos' initial thinking about different advertising is complete.

It's even possible to to talk about past events with a present narrative:

> It is 1994, and Jeff Bezos is driving from New York to Seattle.  On a
>   long, straight stretch of Interstate 80 in Ohio, he realizes that the
>   nature of advertising will change.

Comment: shouldn't the original writer have put a "would" before "redefined" and changed it to "would redefine?"  Seems like the author is mixing POV.  Also, I think there is something more going on with the choice of "would," but I don't know.  "Would" changes the tone of this writing in a way that's hard to put my finger on.  Also, shouldn't it be "In the span of the following two years, Bezos would redefine Amazon.  During this period, he would start to think differently about conventional advertising."  I know this isn't reported speech but shouldn't that form be used here?  Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with deadrat - To demonstrate it another way, we can, as usual, replace "will" with "to be going to". This gives, "In the span of the next two years, Bezos redefined Amazon. During this period, he was going to start to think differently about conventional advertising."

Comment: Perceptive comments.  Yes, the author is mixing his POV.  This is bad style more than bad grammar.  I don't think "following" rescues "next" from possibly misleading the reader into thinking about two years into his own  future.  That interpretation is impossible when the reader gets to "redefined," which is definitely in past time.